# Why does my object keep turning in to a NoneType?

Tags: python, object, reset, nonetype

I am building a Youtube audio sampling program, and I have set an object named time_snip.
The object containing the beginning and end of the sample as milliseconds.
I have noticed that if I enter the time right, I get my expected output, but if I type the time in a wrong format (try/except exception set), and I enter it again in the right way, I get an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'`

The time_snip class:

```py
    class time_snip:
        def __init__(self,start_hour,start_min,start_sec,start_msec,end_hour,end_min,end_sec,end_msec):
            self.start = (start_hour*60*60*1000)+(start_min * 60 * 1000) + (start_sec * 1000)+(start_msec) # Time to milliseconds
            self.end = (end_hour*60*60*1000)+(end_min * 60 * 1000) + (end_sec * 1000)+(end_msec) # Time to milliseconds
            self.start_ind = (str(start_min)+':'+str(start_sec))
            self.end_ind =(str(end_min)+':'+str(end_sec))
```

main code:

```py
    from pytube import YouTube
    from TimeSnip import time_snip
    time_options = input("Would you like to find by time(1) or by word(2)?: ")
    url ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGwNPeEXEDM&ab_channel=SilasLaspada"
    ytd = YouTube(URL)
    def time_set(youtube_object):
            try:
                hr_length = int(ytd.length/3600)
                min_length = int((ytd.length%3600)/60)
                sec_length = ytd.length%60

                print("the video is " + str(hr_length)+':'+str(min_length)+':'+str(sec_length) +'long')
                start_time_srt_format = input("Enter start time in 'hr:min:sec,msec' format: ")
                end_time_srt_format = input("Enter end time in 'hr:min:sec,msec' format: ")
                start_parts = start_time_srt_format.split(':')
                end_parts = end_time_srt_format.split(':')
                start_secmsec = start_parts[2].split(',')
                end_secmsec = end_parts[2].split(',')
                start_hr = int(start_parts[0])
                start_min = int(start_parts[1])
                start_sec = int(start_secmsec[0])
                start_msec = int(start_secmsec[1])
                end_hr = int(end_parts[0])
                end_min = int(end_parts[1])
                end_sec = int(end_secmsec[0])
                end_msec = int(end_secmsec[1])

                word = (str(start_sec)+'-'+str(end_sec))
                timeSnip = time_snip(start_hr, start_min, start_sec, start_msec, end_hr, end_min,end_sec,end_msec)
                return timeSnip
            except IndexError:
                print("Invalid input! Try again!")
                time_set(youtube_object)
    if time_options =='1':
        timeSnip = time_set(ytd)
        word = str(timeSnip.start/1000)+' sec'
    elif time_options =='2':
        word = input("Enter word: ")
```

I have no idea why it's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the except clause, you don't return anything. So, if the exception fires, you call the function again (which is not the right way to do that), but even if that succeeds and returns a value, you throw it away. Change that line to `return time_set(youtube_object)`, but it would be better to make that a while loop instead of a recursive call.

Comment: it would be *correct* to use a while loop.  A function calling itself just to "go back to the beginning" is plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you Tim! I would like to know though, why shouldn't I use reccurtion??

Comment: Recursion has its place, like in mathematical coding or in tree searching, but it has overhead.  If the user can't get the right formatting, you might end up many levels deep here.  From a design point of view, this should be a "loop until the data is valid" pattern.

Comment: In general, it is best to avoid recursion. Each time the recursion is  will add a layer to the call stack.